# Placing section on top of header image

Tags: html, css, header

The code I have for the section is:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(images/football.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

navbar {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


/* Add a black background colour to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a:link,
.topnav a:visited {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
  word-spacing: 7px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover,
.topnav a.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title> DJ's Footy Pool</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <navbar>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#rules">Rules</a>
        <a href="#predictions">Predictions</a>
        <a href="#results">Results</a>
        <a href="#standings">Standings</a>
        <a href="#previous">Previous&nbsp;Winners</a>
      </div>
    </navbar>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <h1>DJ's English Premier League Football Pool</h1>
      <p>The only website you'll need to make predictions, view fixtures and more for our football pool!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

I am trying to place my div text "DJs football pool..." (which sits in between section tags) over my header image. However my section only appears to sit near the bottom of my header rather than over it. I have tried many things but to no avail. What can i do to fix this?

[image]

Desired result (ignore sticky note):

Comment: post the entire code (html+css). Please don't post partial css.

Comment: Can you post an image of the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

[Here an example of text over image](https://codepen.io/jromemcshev/pen/OQdOVw) view full screen (in snippets)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Football_iu_1996.jpg/1200px-Football_iu_1996.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

navbar {
  text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;

}

/* Add a black background colour to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a:link, 
.topnav a:visited {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
    word-spacing: 7px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover, 
.topnav a.active {
border-bottom: 2px solid #e67e22;
}



.centered { /*ADDED CSS*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
        <navbar>
            <div class="topnav">
                <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#rules">Rules</a>
                <a href="#predictions">Predictions</a>
                <a href="#results">Results</a>
                <a href="#standings">Standings</a>
                <a href="#previous">Previous&nbsp;Winners</a>
            </div>
        </navbar>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="row centered">
            <h1>DJ's English Premier League Football Pool</h1>
            <p>The only website you'll need to make predictions, view fixtures and more for our football pool!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost it. The only issue is when I resize the screen to a small screen (such as when I run the code snippet), the text headings appears to land over my navbar, is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: @user9416179 i think its your `navbar`'s css is the cause of that you should look into a [responsive navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h)